# Custom SSL certificate on azure static web app

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-static-website-hosting, azure-static-web-app-routing

I have a static web app building from Git Hub and being deployed to Azure. I need to use a custom SSL certificate, not the one issued by Azure, but I do not see any options on the dashboard to upload a certificate. Is there something I am missing or is this option not supported by Azure?

I created a new static web app, linked a GitHub repo, built the app and everything is working as expected. I then searched through the Azure settings looking for certificate options and did not find one.

Comment: I don’t believe this is supported; why exactly do you need this when SSL is handled for you in the background? What’s your use case?

Answer (score 0):

As esqew mentioned, for Azure Static web app you cannot bind our own certificates like as [App Service WebApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate?tabs=apex).

> By default, Azure Static Web Apps provides an auto-generated domain
> name for your website, but you can point a custom domain to your site.
> Free SSL/TLS certificates are automatically created for the
> auto-generated domain name and any custom domains you may add.

However, if your requirement fits, you may set up a custom domain in Azure Static Web Apps, please take a look at this doc: [static-web-apps/custom-domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/custom-domain)

If you wish, you may share your suggestions on this, you can create an issue in the [Static Web Apps GitHub repository](https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues) || [How can I suggest a new feature?](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/static-web-apps/faq#how-can-i-get-help-or-suggest-a-new-feature-)